# Passing Arrays By Reference

Tags: c++

I'm having an issue of getting garbage out of my array after I pass it to a function. Is this the correct way to pass it to a function that will just print it out?

```
while(infile){
        infile >> batch;
        infile >> amount;
        cout << batch << "     " << amount<< endl;
        totalChocolates[batch-1]+=amount;   
        chocolateBatches[batch-1]++;

    }

    //header();
    print(totalChocolates,chocolateBatches);

    system("pause");
    return 0;

void print(int *total,int *batch)
{
    for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cout << i+1 << "     "  << batch[i] << "     " << total[i] << endl;

    }
}
```

OK I pulled out the function and i'm still getting garbage.

```
while(infile>> batch >> amount){
        //infile >> batch;
        //infile >> amount;
        cout << batch << "     " << amount<< endl;
        totalChocolates[batch-1]+=amount;   
        chocolateBatches[batch-1]++;

    }
    for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cout << i+1 << "     "  << chocolateBatches[i] << "     " << totalChocolates[i] << endl;

    }
```

It returns

> ```
> 1     64
> 8     907
> 18     1133
> 9     636
> 3     1134
> 16     1101
> 6     313
> 7     791
> 7     1130
> 1     1221
> 20     332
> 22     697
> 6     807
> 2     36
> 2     747
> 16     1219
> 3     859
> 18     639
> 18     312
> 7     1079
> 10     1074
> 5     678
> 18     59
> 1     -858993418     -858960818
> 2     -858993429     -858971910
> 3     -858993421     -858963346
> 4     -858993431     -858970692
> 5     -858993427     -858963901
> 6     -858993416     -858961011
> 7     -858993417     -858960812
> 8     -858993421     -858961874
> 9     -858993417     -858960079
> 10     -858993418     -858960161
> 11     -858993422     -858963562
> 12     -858993428     -858970812
> 13     -858993460     -858993460
> 14     -858993427     -858967859
> 15     -858993422     -858964267
> 16     -858993418     -858954549
> 17     -858993423     -858966453
> 18     -858993423     -858964725
> 19     -858993460     -858993460
> 20     -858993433     -858973375
> 21     -858993419     -858963644
> 22     -858993426     -858968664
> 23     -858993456     -858993060
> 24     -858993460     -858993460
> 25     -858993455     -858990222
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

Comment: Wrong, wrong, wrong. You must never peform input unguarded. `infile >> batch;` provides **no** guarantee that it is legal to read `batch`. It should be `while (infile >> batch >> amount) { /* ... */ }`.

Comment: How are you determining `size` in the `print` function?

Comment: If you are using c++, use a `vector`. Using arrays in C++ for things like this is like opening a soda can with a hammer.

Comment: Have you made sure to initialise the arrays with zeros first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much, yes. The issue is, you are not properly using the size of the array, so you are probably just running into the uninitialized space at the end. Also pass a size into the `print` function so you don't run off the end.

EDIT: Although do take heed of Kerrek's warning in your question comments.

Comment: Size is a const int I declared globally

Comment: But are you sure you read all elements into the array up to `size`?

Comment: What is the garbage you are getting?

Comment: You're not writing to every element of the array (via batch). As Dan says in your comments, `vector` is probably better to do this with.

Comment: I don't understand what I'm doing wrong to get the negative number back out of the array.

Comment: You're probably not writing to every element in your array, since the negative numbers are probably uninitialized values.

Comment: I initialized all to 0 first and it works fine now!  Thanks guys!